# What to use, now that Facebook Chat API is deprecated?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xmpp

At first, I used `chat.facebook.com` to send message to Facebook friends,
but using `chat.facebook.com` is now deprecated, and applications cannot use the Facebook messaging feature any more.

Is there any other way to use Facebook chat except using `chat.facebook.com`?
I've googled but I can't find any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way, the Chat API is deprecated and there is no alternative way. You can only build Apps for the Messenger, as it is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/overview

Comment: in the link you provided , i font sample code for sending image , video and sound clips but not the message ... is it possible to send message with messenger ?

Comment: afaik it´s not. meaning, you can´t create your own messenger app.